# How to set string to datetime widget?

Tags: documentum, xcp2.x

The title is self explanatory. I am having difficulties setting a string value to a date time widget.

XCP has a build in function stringToDate

which i use in these examples...

```
 1. stringToDate('5-5-2009') 
 2. stringToDate('05-05-2009')  
 3. stringToDate('5/5/2009')
```

But non of them work. What am I missing here ?

Also i set the value of the widget in the behaviors tab of the date widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `Date-Time Input` widget then you need to use `dateToString` not `stringToDate`.

Comment: Date-Time Input requires object type `Date` as parameter. I will use dateToString if i want to store the Date-Time Input as string somewhere. But that is what i already did, and now i want to return that stored string in the widget for display. Which will intuitively mean i need to use stringToDate. But the case is,it accepts the input but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It's dependent to the format in which you save your date to string value. If we save the Date-Time Input widget value in this format:

```
dateToString('12-12-2018', 'm-d-Y')
```

then doing a :

`stringToDate(savedvalue)` will work only when the format saved was `'m-d-Y'`. It wasn't working before because i saved it as `'d-m-Y'.`